# Deserializing into Object when class is in default package on android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have an application that queries a server (not under my control).
The server returns a serialized object. I have the model for the class - however the problem is that the class is in "default package"... something not recognizable by Android ClassLoader.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: "How can I resolve this issue?" -- Tell whoever created the server that returning serialized objects is a truly awful implementation. They should use XML or JSON or Thrift or Protocol Buffers or something else that is platform-neutral. In terms of your code, though, I have no idea how to deal with this issue -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

And tell whoever created the class, possibly yourself, that Java classes within packages haven't been able to access classes not within packages since Java 1.4 came out, about eight years ago. Put the class into a package.

Comment: Wondering if this can be done by creating a custom class loader specifically for this purpose?